# jupyter notebook loss nan

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In colab, this code works but in jupyter notebook it's not working. loss value is "loss: 2.3014" or "loss: 2.3013" or loss nan. How can i fix this? why is this happen?

```
img_rows = 28
img_cols = 28

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

num_classes = 10

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: What do you mean not working?

Comment: accuracy and loss value are not change. The same value keeps outputting